# What is "Process finished with exit code 500" ？

Tags: c#, windows

When I run App1 project to started another process(App2.exe), the program quickly exited itself, and then I got this information.

"Process finished with exit code 500"

Originally, I thought this situation should be very common, but I didn't find the information about this exit code on the search engine.

What the hell is going on? I feel very confused.

```
//App1
using System.Diagnostics;

var app2 = new Process()
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "App2.exe",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = false
    }
};
app2.Start();
```

```
// App2 
while (true)
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Input is " + input);
}
```

Here is the solution, you can reproduce it on your own computer.

https://github.com/Andy-AO/Shared/tree/master/exit_code_500

Comment: Please provide necessary code as part of your question. You can include the GitHub link if you want, but you also need to provide the necessary code as text in your question.

Comment: You made an http connection and the status return was 500.  Error 500 indicates after the connection complete the server had an error will processing the request.  Only way of finding the issue is to debug the server code or check server log files.  Most likely the request did not meet the server requirements.

Comment: @jdweng I am not connected to the server, just started another process. The complete code has been pasted.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Thanks. The complete code has been pasted.

Comment: "the program", which program are you talking about here, there are two in play.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen "When I run App1 project"

Comment: The connection to the process is HTTP.  The connection is buried in the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem occurs when I run it in Rider, but it does not occur when I run it in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In rider, for example, this error is displayed if requestedExecutionLevel=requireAdministrator is set and you run the application as a release. Only in debug mode does Rider ask whether it should be restarted with administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce the issue with "exit code 500", for me it's always exit code 0, but anyway.

In this case, Rider only waits for the App1 to exit, not for the App2, and that likely causes the issue.

App1 gets started, spawns a child process and then terminates, which causes Rider to close its PTY instance, and closing PTY terminates all the processes that are connected to it (including the App2).

You can fix the situation by adding a line `app2.WaitForExit();` or `await app2.WaitForExitAsync();` after `app2.Start()`: this will keep App1 alive for at least same time as App2, and will prevent Rider from closing the PTY pipes.